# Function to find the length of a decimal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose I am given a number $a \in \mathbb{R}$ can I define a function $f(a)$ such that it returns the length of the decimal? Here are some examples of what I mean:

$f(-0.3) = 1$

$f(0.31) = 2$

$f(0.314) = 3$

$f(-0.3141) = 4$

$\vdots$

$f(\pi) = \infty$

EDIT: Yes, those who are asking below

$f(0.003) = 3$

The leading zeros in this case should count.

Comment: 31415... is not an integer (integers can only have finitely many digits).

Comment: Okay, sorry that was vague (I am new to mathematics...)  I have edited the post!

Comment: Do you mean something like $f(x) = \min \{ k \in \Bbb N \mid 10^k \cdot x \in \Bbb Z\}$?

Comment: What output do you expect from $f(1/3)$?

Comment: $f(1/3) = \infty$

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that works! Thank you! Is it possible to do it without the min function perhaps? (Just curious)

Comment: No , there is no way to do it without the min-function.

Comment: Do you want $f(0.003)=1$ or $f(0.003)=3$? The accepted answer tosses out those leading zeros (and would give $1$ here).

Comment: As far as I know , for numbers like $\gamma$ (the Euler Mascheroni constant) , $e+\pi$ or $e\cdot \pi$ , it is not known whether their decimal expansion terminates. (Perhaps , I am wrong and just the irrationality is an open problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite interesting in my view.

Let $\mathcal R = \left\{\frac{p}{10^q} \in \mathbb Q: p \in \mathbb Z, q \in \mathbb N_0 \right\}$

Suppose now that whenever we refer to an element of $\mathcal R$ we refer to its "minimal form" $\frac{p}{10^q}$ with $10\not\mid p$.

Denote:
$$\begin{align*} f: \mathcal R\setminus\{0\} &\to \mathbb N\\
{p \over 10^q} &\to \lfloor\log_{10}(|p|)\rfloor +1
\end{align*}$$

I'm taking the liberty to assume that when you mean length you're ignoring the leading zeros as well. If this is the case the denominator just translates the location of the decimal point, thus only the numerator is important.

Homework: Prove that if $x \not \in \mathcal R$ then the decimal expansion of $x$ is not finite and is therefore infinite.

Edit: Since the people the comments are requesting it, here's the formula for $p$ for the minimal form of an element of $\mathcal R$:
$$\begin{align*}\psi: \mathcal R &\to \mathbb Z\\
x&\to x \cdot10^{\min \left\{k \in \mathbb N_0:\;  x \cdot10^k  \in \mathbb Z \right\}}
\end{align*}$$
With this we can reformulate $f$ to evaluate to an arbitrary element whose minimal form we do not know by substituting:
$$\begin{align*}f: \mathcal R\setminus\{0\} &\to \mathbb N\\
x &\to \lfloor \log_{10}(|x|)\rfloor + \min \left\{k \in \mathbb N_0:\;  x \cdot10^k  \in \mathbb Z \right\} + 1  \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for this! All this set theory notation is quite new to me, but I will do my best to understand it. Thanks again!

Comment: What are the input to and output from your function $f$? It seems to me that you need to know the values of $p$ and $q$ before you can take the log in the function $f$. How do you find $f(0.31415)$ say?

Comment: Let's see. If $x=0.003=3/1000$ we get $f(x)=1$. In other words, your function discards the leading zeros of a number in $0,1)$. Was this intended?

Comment: A formula would mean that we just need the number to determine the desired value. This is not the case here. So, this is not actually better than the min-formula above.

Comment: @PeterPhipps For elements of $\mathcal R \setminus \{0\}$ they will exist. This is done a lot in stuff like fields of fractions where one may implicitly write a function through $\frac{p}{q} \to f(p,q)$. If you want to explicitly compute minimal $p$ and $q$ for elements of $\mathcal R$ you may use different formulas using mins, but that wasn't the point.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, I interpreted that as being what the OP wanted since if the length of $-0.3$ is supposed to be $1$ and not $2$, and the length of $-3$ is probably defined as $1$ then I interpreted it as the OP wanting to completely disregarding leading zeros.

Comment: It was the point because it was what the OP was asking.

Comment: Leading zeros probably count for the length, so $0.003$ should return $3$. Also I would assume that only the fractional part is considered. But the author is the one having to clarify this.

Comment: @Peter I didn't interpret it that way, either way I've updated my post to include an explicit formula.

Comment: @PeterPhipps the OP was asking for a function, which I had given. I have now updated the answer to include an explicit answer for an arbitrary element of $\mathcal R \setminus\{0\}$, in my interpretation, that does not assume knowledge of its "minimal form".